# Any Way to Optimize this Query? ORACLE 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

I have this query in a procedure, and it is loading the data really slowly. Is there a faster way to make this query run?

```
SELECT date, price
  FROM ( SELECT date, 
                price,price_src,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY 
                             CASE WHEN price_src = 'mom' THEN 
                                   0 
                                   WHEN price_src = 'dad' THEN 
                                   1 
                                   WHEN price_src = 'other' THEN 
                                   2 
                                   END) AS roworder
           FROM pr.sources e
          WHERE e.home = inTick
            AND price IS NOT NULL
            AND e.security = inVal
            AND e.securityNum = NVL(inSecurity,'FWD')
            AND bc= 'USD' 
            AND date >= NVL(startDate, date)
            AND date <= NVL(endDate, date)
                )
 WHERE roworder = 1
 ORDER BY date;
```

I want to get the pricing for a specific value (`inval`) with a base currency of USD and within a specific date range. The problem is, there is prioritizing involved here. First try and get it from the "mom" pricing source, if that's not available then go to "dad" then go to "other".

Here is a sample of the table:

```
+------------+------+-----+-------------+----------+-----------+--------+
| DATE       | home | bc  | securityNum | security | price_src | price  |
+------------+------+-----+-------------+----------+-----------+--------+
| 2001-05-04 | 3A   | USD | FWD         | 32       | MOM       | 548.54 |
| 2012-05-04 | 3G   | USD | BWD         | 58       | DAD       | 58.54  |
| 2009-05-04 | 3F   | USD | FWD         | 39       | OTHER     | 588.54 |
| 2010-05-04 | 3E   | USD | FWD         | 38       | MOM       | 38.54  |
+------------+------+-----+-------------+----------+-----------+--------+
```

The table has over 2 Million Records. It's supposed to get the price for a certain date for a certain value (could be a currency or property).

The query takes 10 seconds to run (for 1 run) and is getting called in a loop. The accumulation of slow timing for every single execution makes the whole thing slow down.

Comment: Your SELECT statement has been created probably because of existing business rules. If we do not know the business rules behind it is impossible to say if something can be simplified.

Comment: What is the query plan?  What indexes exist?  How many rows in the table?  How selective is each predicate?  How long does the query take to run?  How quickly do you need it to run?  Is this query getting called in a loop?  If so, is the problem that a single execution is too slow?  Or is the problem that executing it thousands of times is cumulatively too slow?

Comment: Well i want to get the pricing for a specific value (inval) with base currency USD and within a specific date range. The problem is, there is prioritizing involved here. First try and get it from the "mom" pricing source, if thats not available then go to "dad" then go to "other".

Comment: @Ramie, you need to answer Justin's questions. A sample table is pretty useless without them (although also an important part).

Comment: @Ramie . . . Would more than one record match the `where` logic for a given price source on a given day?  In other words, is roworder only choosing among price sources or is it also choosing an arbitrary value within a price source?

Comment: @GordonLinoff no the query will only output 1 row (a date and a price)

Comment: @Ben i added the info he was asking (just added it now)

Comment: ... Are there really two columns, named `date` and `date_`?  I'd never be able to tell those apart...  You probably shouldn't be using an upper-bound inclusive range, especially as, if I recall correctly, Oracle is including times in 'date' types: use an exclusive upper-bound (`<`) instead.  Whenever I see one of these case-ordering statements, I always wonder if it would be better to use a translating CTE as temp-table (but have never done the research).

Comment: What does "The indexes that exist i put on the table up there" mean?  I don't see anywhere that you have indicated what indexes are available.  I don't see anywhere that you have indicated what the query plan is.  I don't see where you have indicated how selective each of the predicates are.  If the table has 2 million rows, how many rows does your query return?  Assuming the answer is much less than 2 million, explain to us which filters are filtering out a large number of rows and which are filtering out a relatively small number of rows.

Comment: You haven't @Ramie; you haven't added a query plan or what your current indexes are. It's also not really understandable what you're doing. I don't understand the reason for the ORDER BY at the moment. Are you only selecting one row? It seems like you're updating a large table one row at a time with the output of this query is that correct?

Comment: @ben yes and i'm selecting one row. Also, if you're wondering; there is a c# program that runs this procedure and gets 1 row at a time (which is what this query outputs)

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN`, put the results in the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Without further information I would suggest this:

- see if you can remove the loop and just do a set based operation rather than one row at a time
- add an index on securityNum, security, home, price, bc, date, priceSource
- remove the nvl on inSecurity and create two separate statements depending on if it is null or not

Comment: the loop is c# sided though and i want to try and avoid touching that code.. thx for the suggestion though

Comment: @Ramie The other two suggestions still apply even if you do not remove the loop